# Pandas: Get rolling mean with a add operation in between

Tags: pandas

My Pandas df is like:

```
ID  delta   price
1   -2       4
2    2       5
3   -3       3
4   0.8 
5   0.9 
6   -2.3    
7   2.8 
8   1   
9   1   
10  1   
11  1   
12  1
```

Pandas already has robust mean calculation method in built. I need to use it slightly differently.

So, in my df, price at row 4 would be sum of (a) rolling mean of price in row 1, 2, 3 and (b) delta at row 4.
Once, this is computed: I would move to row 5 for this: (a) rolling mean of price in row 2, 3, 4 and (b) delta at row 5. This would give price at row 5.....

I can iterate over rows to get this but my actual dataframe in quite big and iterating over row would slow things up....any better way to achieve?

Comment: can you provide the expected output for your input example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think we have method in panda can use the pervious calculated value in the next calculation

```
n = 3
for x in df.index[df.price.isna()]:
    df.loc[x,'price'] = (df.loc[x-n:x,'price'].sum() + df.loc[x,'delta'])/4

df
Out[150]: 
    ID  delta     price
0    1   -2.0  4.000000
1    2    2.0  5.000000
2    3   -3.0  3.000000
3    4    0.8  3.200000
4    5    0.9  3.025000
5    6   -2.3  1.731250
6    7    2.8  2.689062
7    8    1.0  2.111328
8    9    1.0  1.882910
9   10    1.0  1.920825
10  11    1.0  1.728766
11  12    1.0  1.633125
```